# Using Variables in Azure CLI and REGEX

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am trying to replace a string between 2 delimiters using Regex in Azure CLI and entering variables into my Regex expression but the syntax I have is not working as expected. I have tried the following script:

```
originalString = "URL":"some-url" "port":"580" "value":"test123"
newValue = "ABC123"
newString = \originalString | sed -e 's/\".*\"/\"newValue\"/'
echo newString
```

The expected output should be "URL":"some-url" "port":"580" "value":"ABC123" but it threw the message "command not found" for the first 3 lines.

It appears I cannot insert variables into my Regex as I tried to do above. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The expected output should be "URL":"some-url" "port":"580" "value":"ABC123" but it threw the message "command not found" for the first 3 lines.

You can use below commands to get the expected results:

```
rithwikstring='"URL":"test-url" "port":"681" "value":"rithwik1234test"'
rithwiknew="ABC123"
resultstring=$(echo $rithwikstring | sed -e "s/\"value\":\"[^\"]*\"/\"value\":\"$rithwiknew\"/")
echo "$resultstring"
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

Comment: This works really well but it would be great if you could explain the script. I can see that the word "value" appears twice in the the third line but I don't understand why. Could you please explain your script.

Comment: First value is to locate the correct place and second value is to replace with this ABC123

Comment: Hi your script works well if there are no spaces after the colon but as soon as I get a string with spaces after the colon it doesn't work. I have modified your script as follows resultstring=$(echo $rithwikstring | sed -e "s/\"value\":[[:space:]]*\"[^\"]*\"/\"value\":[[:space:]]*\"$rithwiknew\"/") That works as far as matching the spaces after the colon but now the resulting string has the symbol [[:space:]]* in it as can be seen below: "URL":"test-url" "port":"681" "value":[[:space:]]*"rithwik1234test" How do I prevent the symbol [[:space:]]* from showing in the resulting string?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/A7I3jZ5.png It works well for even with spaces. If this is not what you want provide me input and expected output, not  with just resultstring

Comment: Here is a test string oldString = '{"connectionUrl":"odbc:sqlserver://SomeIPAddress:PortNumber; domain=SomeUrl; AuthenticationScheme=SomeScheme; integratedSecurity=true; database=Some DB","user":username", "password": "String1234"}' newPassword = 'ABCxyz5678' expectedOutput = '{"connectionUrl":"odbc:sqlserver://SomeIPAddress:PortNumber; domain=SomeUrl; AuthenticationScheme=SomeScheme; integratedSecurity=true; database=Some DB","user":username", "password": "ABCxyz5678"}' The amount of spaces after the colon i.e. "password": ssss"****"  is random.

Comment: But where have you added spaces, give me with spaces in input and howe should be output Is this what you want https://i.imgur.com/Yt3Obez.png

Comment: In my example  "password": ssss"****" the symbol ssss represents the spaces.

Comment: I tried adding a string with spaces in notepad but when I pasted it in the comment the spaces get removed automatically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256639/discussion-between-rithwikbojja-and-eternalcuriosity).